# OpenThread() Returns NULL Win32

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

I feel like there is an obvious answer to this, but it's been eluding me.  I've got some legacy code in C++ here that breaks when it tries to call OpenThread().  I'm running it in Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.  The program first gets the ThreadID of the calling thread, and attempts to open it, like so:

ThreadId threadId = IsThreaded() ? thread_id : ::GetCurrentThreadId();

HANDLE threadHandle = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, threadId);

Now here's what I don't understand: if the thread ID is the current thread's ID, isn't it already open?  Could that be why it's returning NULL?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you're asking for too much access (`THREAD_ALL_ACCESS`), though I'd think that you'd have pretty much all permissions to your own thread.  Try reducing the access to what you really need.

What does `GetLastError()` return?

Update:

Take a look at this comment from MSDN:

> Windows Server 2003 and Windows
>   XP/2000:  The size of the
>   `THREAD_ALL_ACCESS` flag increased on
>   Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista.
>   If an application compiled for Windows
>   Server 2008 and Windows Vista is run
>   on Windows Server 2003 or Windows
>   XP/2000, the `THREAD_ALL_ACCESS` flag is
>   too large and the function specifying
>   this flag fails with
>   `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. To avoid this
>   problem, specify the minimum set of
>   access rights required for the
>   operation. If `THREAD_ALL_ACCESS` must
>   be used, set `_WIN32_WINNT` to the
>   minimum operating system targeted by
>   your application (for example, 
>   `#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP` ). For more information, see Using the Windows
>   Headers

Comment: ThREAD_ALL_ACCESS was apparently the problem.  I used THREAD_SET_INFORMATION and it did the trick.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Try using _beginthreadex instead of OpenThread.
Example:

```
HANDLE hThread;
UINT uiThreadId = 0;
hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,  // Security attributes
    0,  // stack
    &this->ThreadProc,  // Thread proc
    this,   // Thread param
    CREATE_SUSPENDED,   // creation mode
    &uiThreadId);   // Thread ID

if (hThread != NULL){
    //SetThreadPriority(hThread, THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST);
    ResumeThread(hThread);
    m_hThread = hThread;
}
else{
    eRetVal = err_ThreadStartErr;
}
```