# Is it not possible to obtain a handle from a thread ID?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, handle

In the classic book "Multithreading Applications in Win32", at page 31, there is a statement as follows:

> To enforce security, it is not possible to obtain a handle from a
>   thread ID.

However, I know there is a well-known API, i.e. `OpenThread`, can do this job.

Is this a bug of the book?

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Multithreading-Applications-Win32-Complete-Threads/dp/0201442345) was published in 1996; long before the Windows XP/2003 where the [function you mention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335(v=vs.85).aspx) was added. I would definitely recommend considering getting a newer book.

Comment: @Andrew, Could you make your comment to an answer? I will choose it as an answer.

Comment: Comment posted as answer! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book in question [Multithreading Applications in Win32](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201442345) was published in 1996, which predates the operating systems where the [OpenThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335(v=vs.85).aspx) function was available. So, the book is simply out of date.

---

The above MSDN link says that `OpenThread()` requires WindowsXP/2003. However, as [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179634/luke) noted in a comment below, it seems this function was also in Windows 2000. (Which still predates the book in question, but I thought it worthwhile to clarify.

References:

1. [OpenThread returns null Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069888/237838)
2. [re: OpenThread](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=2095)
3. [Win32::API error - OpenThread](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=370766)

Comment: OpenThread was present in Windows 2000, but your point still stands.  It is unfortunate that Microsoft is scrubbing the MSDN documentation like this.

Comment: @Luke I've found some relevant information and added it to the answer. Thanks for the heads-up on that!